# Return multiple results in the where clause using case statement

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to return possible multiple values in the where clause.

Here is my query

```
SELECT *, 
                            ISNULL(nStatus, '0') Status,
                            ISNULL(dtUsed, 0) dtUsed,
                            ISNULL(sStaffID, '') StaffID,
                            ISNULL((SELECT sName FROM GCS_tbBranch WHERE nSeq=GCS_tbGC.nBranchNo), '') nBranchName,
                            ISNULL((SELECT dtValidEnd FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo = GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) dtValidUntil,
                            ISNULL((SELECT dtCreated FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo=GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) dtCreated, 
                            ISNULL((SELECT nPrice FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo=GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) nPrice,
                            ISNULL(sRemarks, ' ') sRemarks 
                            FROM GCS_tbGC WHERE sGCNo LIKE @sGCNo+'%' AND nGroupSeq IN (SELECT nGroupNo FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE
                            CASE
                            WHEN @sClass = 'QNS' OR @sClass = 'IFL' THEN (sClass = 'QNS' OR sClass = 'IFL')
                            ELSE
                            @sClass
                            END
                            )
```

Wherein, if the variable @sClass is holding either `'QNS' or 'IFL'` it would return records that has the `sClass = 'QNS' OR sClass = 'IFL'`, otherwise, just return the value of the @sClass variable.

EDIT: Whenever I run this query, it would return this exception

```
Incorrect syntax near ' = ' is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a CASE expression is the right tool for this job.  Try query below.

```
SELECT *, 
                            ISNULL(nStatus, '0') Status,
                            ISNULL(dtUsed, 0) dtUsed,
                            ISNULL(sStaffID, '') StaffID,
                            ISNULL((SELECT sName FROM GCS_tbBranch WHERE nSeq=GCS_tbGC.nBranchNo), '') nBranchName,
                            ISNULL((SELECT dtValidEnd FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo = GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) dtValidUntil,
                            ISNULL((SELECT dtCreated FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo=GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) dtCreated, 
                            ISNULL((SELECT nPrice FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo=GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) nPrice,
                            ISNULL(sRemarks, ' ') sRemarks 
FROM GCS_tbGC 
WHERE sGCNo LIKE @sGCNo+'%' 
AND nGroupSeq IN (
    SELECT nGroupNo 
    FROM GCS_tbGCGroup 
    WHERE
        @sClass IN('QNS', 'IFL') AND sClass IN('QNS', 'IFL')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @sClass
    WHERE
        @sClass NOT IN('QNS', 'IFL')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` returns scalar and should be used like one -- you can't manipulate conditions the way you want.
Try simpler expressions:

```
and (
    nGroupSeq = @sClass 
    or @sClass = 'QNS' and nGroupSeq = 'IFL'
    or @sClass = 'IFL' and nGroupSeq = 'QNZ'
)
```

or

```
and (
    nGroupSeq = @sClass 
    or @sClass in ('QNS', 'IFL') and nGroupSeq in ('QNS', 'IFL'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to pull this off.

Thinking that I can insert the case statement inside an IN keyword, I can use 2 case statements given the situation.

This is my solution.

```
SELECT *, 
                            ISNULL(nStatus, '0') Status,
                            ISNULL(dtUsed, 0) dtUsed,
                            ISNULL(sStaffID, '') StaffID,
                            ISNULL((SELECT sName FROM GCS_tbBranch WHERE nSeq=GCS_tbGC.nBranchNo), '') nBranchName,
                            ISNULL((SELECT dtValidEnd FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo = GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) dtValidUntil,
                            ISNULL((SELECT dtCreated FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo=GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) dtCreated, 
                            ISNULL((SELECT nPrice FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE nGroupNo=GCS_tbGC.nGroupSeq), 0) nPrice,
                            ISNULL(sRemarks, ' ') sRemarks 
                            FROM GCS_tbGC WHERE sGCNo LIKE @sGCNo+'%' AND nGroupSeq IN (SELECT nGroupNo FROM GCS_tbGCGroup WHERE sClass IN (
                            CASE @sClass
                            WHEN 'QNS' THEN 'IFL'
                            WHEN 'IFL' THEN 'IFL'
                            ELSE
                            @sClass
                            END
                            ,
                            CASE @sClass
                            WHEN 'QNS' THEN 'QNS'
                            WHEN 'IFL' THEN 'QNS'
                            ELSE
                            ''
                            END
                            )
                            )
```

Any better queries are welcome. I hope you can give suggestion to further shorten / enhance the query. Thanks and more power!